# SQL Developer Status : Failure - I/O Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: sql, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am a newbie don't know how to use SQL developer. whether I need Oracle database for installing in windows 10 what are these hr and sys users and how to know their passwords. please help me I know this question is asked many times but really, believe me, I have searched a lot but can't find a working solution for it.

Screenshot of my pc:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you installed Oracle SQL Developer, and you don't know what to do next?

[Here's the answer in long-form](https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303), with lots of pictures and links.

The short answer: SQL Developer is JUST a client. You need a server to connect to, and that server IS the Oracle Database.

You can get your own running on the same machine as SQL Developer. [Oracle XE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html) is free and lightweight.

Or you can get our [VirtualBox appliance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html) that has everything already going - a database with test data, hands-on-learning labs, and much more - also FREE.

[image]

Of the two, I recommend VirtualBox, because it's more up to date, and it's juts an image - it won't 'pollute' your machine in case you decide to stop using the DB. You can just nuke the image.

Comment: If you install XE, you'll supply an admin password for the SYS and SYSTEM accounts. If you use the VBOX image, ALL of the passwords are 'oracle'

Comment: PS if you go with XE - use SYSTEM to unlock HR or create your own account. If you use the VBOX, login as HR - dont' use the admin accounts as it'll be easier to 'screw something up'

Comment: Sir, I am downloading Virtualbox, I think it is easy to learn as given in tutorial what u have suggested.

Comment: @vikas2cc when you've got it downloaded, this might help you get started http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/02/introducing-the-otn-developer-day-database-12c-virtualbox-image/