# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I'm running Oracle sql developer 20.4 for the first time and I can't make a connection due to the error shown in the picture. Any idea how to solve this ? all suggested solutions are on Windows.

Comment: most likely answer is because you do not actually have a database named XE running on your machine - sql developer is simply a client for talking to the database

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49707627/266304); except you'll *have* to use a VM (or a cloud solution), as Oracle DB doesn't run natively on macOS any more.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I guess I will follow @AlexPoole solution as after research it seems the only one.

Comment: some options here to help you get started https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/02/im-a-student-studying-oracle-and-i-need-a-database-help/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thank you for the info ! After installing the oracle sql vm on virtual box, the icons look tiny, Do you have a solution for this issue ? I'm running Big sur

Comment: You can resize the vm window, but I don't really use it and just connect from your Mac directly

Comment: @thatjeffsmith are you suggesting that I keep the virtual box open and use the oracle sql developer I have on my mac to talk to each other ? but how ?

Comment: that's exactly what i'm suggesting, make your connection properties user: HR password: oracle server: localhost port:1521 service: orcl

Comment: @thatjeffsmith it worked, thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

As @thatjeffsmith said, if you want to learn and test something, search for "Unlocking HR schema". You will find a detailed instructions on how to unlock and connect to HR schema and then you can test anything you want.

best of luck to you.

Comment: You need a database before you can unlock a schema *8-)